# Wrapping IQueryable

Tags: .net, linq

I'm using Entity Framework as my ORM and each of my classes implements an interface that basically represents table structures (one readonly property for each field). These interfaces are meant to be shared between assemblies for different applications. They don't support any writing operations.

Right now EF allows me to use instances of IQueryable<EntityClass>. What I'd like to have is support for IQueryable<IEntityInterface> that will be on top of it. Needless to say I expect to be able to perform Where operations using interface properties.

Is it feasible at all, or I'm losing my time here? I tried implementing my own IQueryProvider and ExpressionVisitor but so far it haven't worked out so well. I have very little experience regarding LINQ's expression structures. Is it the way to go or there's another, better way?

Comment: Just so that I understand the question better, what is an example use case where your interfaces and concrete classes are incompatible? That is, where is it hurting you to have `IQueryable<EntityClass>`?

Comment: I'd advise against exposing the IQueryable interface too high up the stack.

Comment: this seems like an odd thing to do.  what does your IEntityInterface contract look like?  is it a proxy on top of the EntityClass?  does it add new functionality?

Comment: I would like to avoid dependencies on ORM attached objects in some scenarios where I only need read access to data, like reports or within some decision-making analysis.

Comment: Indeed, the interface is just a proxy with no new functionalities, it only exposes a datatable's fields as readonly properties. I will use these interfaces as parameters for extension methods so that whatever implements a particular data structure can benefit from it, but that's about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may not be fully understanding what you want to do with this, but the common approach I have seen taken (and I myself have taken) is to create a repository using generics.  If you put in constraints for your generics, you can use the properties of your entity interface.  Something like this...

```
public interface IRepository<T>
    where T : class, IEntityInterface 
{
    T FindById(int id);
    IQueryable<T> All { get; }
}

public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> 
    where T : class, IEntityInterface 
{
    public T FindById(int id) 
    {
        //Uses the Id property from the interface
        return All.Where(t => t.Id == id).Single();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> All
    {
        get
        {
            //Get DbContext instance from somewhere
            return _dbContext.Set<T>();
        }
    }
}

public interface IEntityInterface 
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

You can then go into further generics by making the entity interface a generic type as well.  And this all plays well with dependency injection and/or a factory pattern (if you're into that).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if I pass around an instance of IRepository<IEntityInterface> and make queries from the All property, the LINQ query provider will not be able to perform operations on server side. This is what I'd like to be able to do.

Comment: Queries from an IQueryable<T> object are executed and hydrated into memory at the time that you enumerate the query object.  You can keep building up additional where clauses on an IQueryable<T> object and the query will not be executed until you call ToList() or loop through the collection with a foreach.  This is referred to as [deferred execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/bb397906.aspx).

Comment: So you can use the repository to get access to the initial queryable object, and then pass around the queryable object to build up the query you need.  (not necessarily passing around the repository object).

Comment: I'll try it again but so far my experience with queryable wrappers taught me that for where clauses to work on these, the whole data set must be pulled from the database first. EF LINQ query provider won't even try to map interface properties as fields, so whatever LINQ expression I do using interface references won't work, unless if used in a LINQ to Objects fashion. What I'd like to do is to put myself right between IQueryable<IEntityInterface> and the basic EF provider. There, I'll provide my own mapping scheme to transform expressions in actual EF objects query expression.

Comment: The solution I've given may meet your needs and is what I've seen done in the industry.  IMHO, the solution you are suggesting may be more work than it is worth.  If you are having issues with deferred queries hitting the database before you would expect, you may want to post some questions about solving that issue.  Just my two cents. =)

Comment: I'm just trying not to be tied up too tight with EF while leveraging the power of LINQ to give a selected few developers the ability to fetch data with as little restraints as possible. I'm not sure I'm explaining it right, english isn't my main language... you can think of it as an ORM abstraction layer for readonly operations, basically.